# AggregateException ctor DefaultMessage Error on one machine but not the other

Tags: c#, default, aggregate

I have just tested a C# program that does some threaded processing. On my own PC which runs win7 (32-bit) the program runs fine, but when I try it on a 64bit Windows Server 2008 Machine, the same program gives me "AggregateException ctor DefaultMessage"

I only have the exe at the moment, can any one guide me towards any solution, has any one solved a problem like this before?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, we have solved this before. It always involves reading and changing source code.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem while testing my application on a WindowsXP 32bit machine, which was developed on a Windows7 32bit machine. It's a Tasks continuation spaghetti calling WCF services, where I'm trying to reproduce a `CommunicationException` by plugging off the internet cable. My WCF services use basicHttpBinding and Streamed mode, so when I plug off the cable I'm catching an `IOException`. I then cancel the rest of the Tasks in the chain and restart the whole process. While this works on my dev environment, when I try it on the XP machine I'm getting an unhandled...

Comment: ... `AggregateException`. I'm looking into it at the moment. Probably going to start a new question.

Comment: Yeah well, I just realized this question is 1,5 years old.